# set a value in .html file from an external .js file

Tags: javascript, html

i have a main.js that handles Key pressed. and i have a index.html that i want to recieve some variables from main.js and make decisions about it. for example i want to send a url from main.js to index.html .. i try this code in my main.js but not worked.

```
document.getElementById("url").value = "http://example.com";
```

in my index.html i have:

```
<form name="Params">
<input id="url" type="hidden" value="">
</form>
```

i just want to set value of my url input object from main.js.
any help?

Comment: Are you sure you've included your .js file in the .html file i.e. `<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></javascript>` between your `<head>` tags?

Comment: You have to execute the code once the input field exists, i.e. the DOM is ready.

Comment: What browser are you using? Are you getting any script errors, check in debug mode: IE = F12, Chrome = CTRL+SHIFT+J script window.  Also place your code block in a `window.onload = function() { // do code };` function in your .js file.

Answer (score 0):

It is important when did you call value assignment. It must be after DOM loaded. To do this you can try one of the followings.

1. Easiest way is just place your main.js script tag after `/body` close tag. it should work.
2. Assign the value in a function in main.js and call that function `onload` event.

--main.js

```
function assignValue()
{
    document.getElementById("url").value = "http://example.com";
}
```

--index.html

```
<body onload="assignValue()" >
```

Comment: i dont want to set the value in an OnLoad event. i want to set the value when a specific key pressed...

Comment: "i want to recieve some variables from main.js and make decisions about it" sounds like he wants the value in first place. if it is the event in main.js. he doesn't need to pass variable at all.

Comment: can you send us little more information than. how you handle the event and you html layout. You are not using a iframe or something like that right.

Comment: for exemple i make my decision in main.js that a specific url must send to index.html... how can i send that url to index.html? ... i used input, but not worked

Comment: if the main.js can handle keyPress event correctly it means it is in the document. and you can set the value as your code. It should work. How do you know it is not working. Just set the type="text" from hidden and see what is happening. And check the html file if there is another object with id="url".

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine to me but perhaps the code that triggers it isn't being fired. You haven't included the other part of your code that triggers the setting of the URL.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the reason it hasn't worked is because you're not waiting for [DOM to initialize](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/event/domready.html) and the Web Browser has finished parsing the HTML.

The simplest 'fix' for this problem would be to hook into the `window.onload` callback in your `main.js` file:

```
// Wait for the DOM to finish loading.
var previousOnload = window.onload;
window.onload = function () {

    // Execute any other `onload` function which may have been bound previously.
    if (typeof previousOnload === 'function') {
        previousOnload();
    }

    document.getElementById("url").value = "http://example.com";
});
```

However, it is preferred to listen for the DOM Ready event instead; if you're using jQuery then you can simply write:

```
// Wait for the DOM to initialize first.
$(function () { 
    document.getElementById("url").value = "http://example.com";    
});
```

If you don't want to depend on jQuery then you could have a look into the super-lightweight [DOMReady.js](https://github.com/ded/domready/)